# Is there a Pyomo version for Python for Windows 11?

Tags: python, version, pyomo, python-3.10, windows-11

I am trying to pip install pyomo but it was given this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyomo.py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyomo.py

Please, how do I resolve this?

Comment: You're tying to install a package called `pyomo.py` from PyPi. Does this package exist?

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 and python 3.10, Install is successful